# how to make pdf annotation as read only using itext?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, itextpdf

I am trying to make a program that multiple users can share one PDF document , and every one can put his comments on the PDF using add sticky note without changing/modifying other notes.
For example , 
The program will transfer that PDF file to another person for review and checking , the reviewer will put his comments on the PDF and send it to Approver person . The approver can't edit reviewer comments and change it at all , he can add new sticky note to it for his comments.

if I use the security on the PDF ( ~ PdfWriter.AllowModifyAnnotations ) , I will disable entering new sticky note.

is there any solution for that ?

please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: Which programs do your users user? I ask because given the appropriate program, a read-only annotation can be edited nonetheless.

Comment: i am using JSP ( java server page) , a user will upload PDF with his comments and the system will forword the file to the assgined person ( say person B ) . person B can't edit all prevoius comments by previous users. he can only add his comment to the file and upload it to the system again. i want to know how can I make the comments read only if other people open the PDF file.they can read the content and add notes only.

Comment: *person B can't edit all prevoius comments by previous users. he can only add his comment to the file and upload it to the system again.* - using which program shall person B be unable to edit previous comments but be able to add new ones?

Comment: "using which program shall person B be unable to edit previous comments but be able to add new ones?" , it is normal PDF program. Person B will receive the PDF in email , he will read , check and put his comments on the PDF he received. he will open the PDF file as normal , using acrobat reader or PDF professional or whatever tools opening the PDF file. when he is opening the PDF using acrobat reader , he will not be able to adjust other people notes .

Comment: *using acrobat reader or PDF professional or whatever tools opening the PDF file* - some such programs allow to ignore the read/only property of annotations. That's why I asked. *when he is opening the PDF using acrobat reader , he will not be able to adjust other people notes* - ah, ok, so it suffices if those notes cannot be changed in Adobe Acrobat Reader (not pro).

Comment: now how can I make my java program to disable editing the comments , comments will be read only. it is the same like how we secure full PDF by allowing some permission only ( allow print only for example ) ,  user can't edit the file at all. I need the same to do with annotation , enable adding and editing new one and disable editing the exist previous one.

Comment: Annotations have flags. One of these flags is a read-only flag. My approach would be to iterate over the annotations of all pages and set their read-only flag. I have not yet had the time to test this, though.

Comment: please Sir , if you could test this and show me how it can be done I would appreciate this very much from you because I searched in many websites but I could not find anything. I am waiting your respond Sir .. thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

PDF annotation objects can have flags; one of these flags is a read-only flag. Thus, you only have to iterate over all annotations on all pages and set their respective read-only flag.

---

In iText 5.5.x this can be done like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resourceStream);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);

for (int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
{
    PdfDictionary pageDictionary = reader.getPageN(page);
    PdfArray annotationArray = pageDictionary.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    if (annotationArray == null)
        continue;
    for (PdfObject object : annotationArray)
    {
        PdfObject directObject = PdfReader.getPdfObject(object);
        if (directObject instanceof PdfDictionary)
        {
            PdfDictionary annotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary) directObject;
            PdfNumber flagsNumber = annotationDictionary.getAsNumber(PdfName.F);
            int flags = flagsNumber != null ? flagsNumber.intValue() : 0;
            flags |= PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_READONLY;
            annotationDictionary.put(PdfName.F, new PdfNumber(flags));
        }
    }
}

stamper.close();
```

*(iText 5 [MarkAnnotationReadOnly.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/annotate/MarkAnnotationReadOnly.java#L49))*

---

In iText 7.0.x it can be done like this

```
try (   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(resourceStream);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter) )
{
    for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
    {
        PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDocument.getPage(page);
        for (PdfAnnotation pdfAnnotation : pdfPage.getAnnotations())
        {
            pdfAnnotation.setFlag(PdfAnnotation.READ_ONLY);
        }
    }
}
```

*(iText 7 [MarkAnnotationReadOnly.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/annotate/MarkAnnotationReadOnly.java#L45))*

Only the kernel iText 7 artifact is required.

Comment: If this works for you, you might want to accept the answer (click on the tick at its upper left).